# Updating redux state based on service response

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk, immer.js

I have created an actions and reducers using createSlice.

In one of the actions, I am calling the service using a collection from state. I want to update the state data based on response from the service.

On success I want to update `state.locations` and on failure, I want to update `state.errorData`.

```
const ManageInventoriesState = createSlice({
  name: "ManageInventoriesReducer",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateIventoryLocations: (state) => {
      updateService(state.oprationsList).then((resp) => {
          state.locations = resp.data;
      }).catch((err) => {
        state.errorData = err.data;
      });
    },
  },
});
```

But when I am trying to do this, I am getting following error,

> Can not perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked.

How to do it correctly.

From UI I am just dispatching the action (UI is a [connected component](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)).

```
dispatch(updateIventoryLocations());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simsons, that is anti-pattern of reducers. [Reducers need to be Pure Functions](https://redux.js.org/glossary#reducer) and shouldn't include an asynchronous call.

Also, your reducer needs to return the updated state, but nothing has been returned.

You can update it:

**Reducer**

```js
updateIventoryLocations: (state, action) => ({ ...state, locations: action.payload })
```

And you call the action with the result of the service:

```js
updateService(state.oprationsList).then((resp) => {
  dispatch(updateIventoryLocations(resp.data));
});
```

Comment: How will I call updateService with state.oprationsList. UI does not have access to state object directly.

Comment: why you are not able to access the `opratiosList`? can you share your component code which calls the dispatch?

Comment: My bad, looks like I have access to the list. Looking into it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again Yash, for bring me back to the truth "Reducers should be pure functions"

Comment: :) no problem, i am appreciated if it helped you